# Drag and Drop Image to anyplace on another image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyone know what can I use to Drag and drop an image anywhere on another image? I tried searching but the image will be drop on a certain position

Answer (score 3):

Check the snippet below from [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop), it appears to do what you're looking for:

```css
#gate {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 83px;
  height: 46px;
}

#ball {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the ball.</p>

<img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/soccer-gate.svg" id="gate" class="droppable">

<img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball">

<script>
  let currentDroppable = null;

  ball.onmousedown = function(event) {

    let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    ball.style.position = 'absolute';
    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.append(ball);

    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
      ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
      ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

      ball.hidden = true;
      let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      ball.hidden = false;

      if (!elemBelow) return;

      let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.droppable');
      if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
        if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
          leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
        }
        currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
        if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
          // (maybe just left the droppable)
          enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
        }
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    ball.onmouseup = function() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      ball.onmouseup = null;
    };

  };

  function enterDroppable(elem) {
    elem.style.background = 'pink';
  }

  function leaveDroppable(elem) {
    elem.style.background = '';
  }

  ball.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  };
</script>
```